# How pass parameters by using a function in stored procedures without creating variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The correct syntax is

```
-- @input is from an external parameter outside the scope of the execution
DECLARE @param_date datetime = dbo.udf_GetSomeValue(@input)
EXEC dbo.myproc @param_date
```

My goal is to have **shorthand** that does not need the declared variable like:

```
EXEC dbo.myproc dbo.udf_GetSomeValue(@input)
```

Is there a way to this?

Comment: Well, you know how to do what you want.  SQL Server does not evaluate parameters for `exec`.

Comment: DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = 'EXEC myproc ''' + CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(12)) + ''''
EXEC (@SQL)  --- > found a way indirectly.. but equally dumb.

Comment: @earl not equally dumb - much more dumb. What do you have against declaring a variable?

Comment: @dStanley - not sure if i even have to state it as it is quite obvious.  It's more elegant and concise.  The extra variable is not necessary and the restriction is only due to the parsing constraints of the language.   "EXEC myproc GETDATE()" is self explanatory and only restricted due to this "evaluation" constraints.   In JavaScript the better equivalent is EVAL which is more forgiving and more powerful than EXEC.  I am trying to explore a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.myproc @param DATE AS SELECT COALESCE(@param,GETDATE());`
```

**Now:**

```
EXEC dbo.myproc @param = NULL;
```

**does the same thing as:**

```
EXEC dbo.myproc @param = GETDATE();
```

... except without the error  ;)

Comment: nice try.. it does work of course and i can also do this using defaults.  I was aiming for other UDF or better yet an expression like  EXEC dbo.myproc (SELECT MAX(start_date) from data inner join...).   Thanks a lot. :))   I wish i could upvote your answer but it might misrepresent a correct answer.  I will update the question instead so that non-deterministic functions are left out.